# PygObject and INTERP_BILINEAR

Tags: python, gtk, raspberry-pi3, raspbian, pygobject

I'm working on a little project on a Raspberry Pi, and playing with PygObject for the first time.

I'm trying to scale an image, and every example I find says I need to use a flag named INTERP_BILINEAR, but I can't find that anywhere within PygObject/Gtk. I've grep'ed the code base and can't seem to find any reference to INTERP_BILINEAR. I'm sure I'm missing something really obvious, but I don't know what.

```
pixbuf = GdkPixbuf.Pixbuf.new_from_file(random.choice(pics))
pixbuf = pixbuf.scale_simple(100, 100, <some_package>.INTERP_BILINEAR)

img = Gtk.image_new_from_pixbuf(pixbuf)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`INTERP_BILINEAR` is `GdkPixbuf.InterpType.BILINEAR`. I searched for `INTERP_BILINEAR` in the results of calling `help("GdkPixbuf")`. Often, Gtk and related modules use this type of formatting when referencing their objects.

Comment: That did the trick. Thank you.